# How do I read the thrown error content and use it in an IF statement

Tags: powershell

I want to "grab" the content of the exception with *try{}/Catch{}* and use an IF to search for something inside it. Can someone tell me how can I use the *$PSItem.Exception* ? Thank you !

```
try {
  get-process ...
}
catch {
    if (PSItem.Exception ....) { 
        Write-Error -Message "just move on !" -ErrorAction continue
    }
    else {
        throw PSItem.Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "something"?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: You can directly use `$_.Exception.Message` in catch block to capture the only error message too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item thrown from a try/catch block (this is true for any exception in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)) is an `ErrorRecord` type (you can see its members on msdn).  Inside this record, the actual exception is under `$PSItem.Exception` (or `$_` instead of `$PSItem`); this member also has a string of the exception message under the `Message` member on `Exception`.  If you use the `ErrorRecord#ToString` method, you get this directly without having to dig through the members:

```
"$PSItem"
```

You can then check the error message for whatever you like:

```
if ("$PSItem" -like '*Access denied*') {
```

As a side-note, do not re-throw the exception, just throw the original error record like so:

```
else {
    throw
}
```

Comment: Additional to this, sometimes you need to look deeper into the exception using the `InnerException` property of any .net exception. When the chain stops, then the value of the property is empty. For example `$_.Exception.InnerException.InnerException` etc